# Dynamic If statement generation in python

Tags: python, if-statement

I need to generate an if statement in python based on the number of unique values in a dataframe column. See below. Can you please suggest a way that I can accomplish this?

Update:

```
    def test_fail_label(row):
        lab=""
        if (row['#_Failed_Consumption'] > 0 and row['#_Failed_Energy Type']==0 and row['#_Failed_Rating']==0):
            lab = 'Failed '+str(row['#_Failed_Consumption'])+ ' Consumption tests'
        elif (row['#_Failed_Consumption'] > 0 and row['#_Failed_Energy Type']==0 and row['#_Failed_Rating']>0):
            lab = 'Failed '+str(row['#_Failed_Consumption'])+ ' Consumption tests & '+str(row['#_Failed_Rating'])+' Rating tests'
        elif (row['#_Failed_Consumption'] == 0 and row['#_Failed_Energy Type']==0 and row['#_Failed_Rating']>0):
            lab = 'Failed '+str(row['#_Failed_Rating'])+' Rating tests'
        elif (row['#_Failed_Consumption'] == 0 and row['#_Failed_Energy Type']>0 and row['#_Failed_Rating']==0):
            lab = 'Failed '+str(row['#_Failed_Energy Type'])+ ' Energy Type tests'
        elif (row['#_Failed_Consumption'] == 0 and row['#_Failed_Energy Type']>0 and row['#_Failed_Rating']>0):
            lab = 'Failed '+str(row['#_Failed_Energy Type'])+ ' Energy Type tests & '+str(row['#_Failed_Rating'])+' Rating tests'
        elif (row['#_Failed_Consumption'] > 0 and row['#_Failed_Energy Type']>0 and row['#_Failed_Rating']==0):
            lab = 'Failed '+str(row['#_Failed_Consumption'])+ ' Consumption tests & '+str(row['#_Failed_Energy Type'])+' Energy Type tests'
        elif (row['#_Failed_Consumption'] > 0 and row['#_Failed_Energy Type']>0 and row['#_Failed_Rating']>0):
            lab = 'Failed '+str(row['#_Failed_Consumption'])+ ' Consumption tests & '+str(row['#_Failed_Energy Type'])+' Energy Type tests &'+str(row['#_Failed_Rating'])+' Rating tests'   
        elif (row['#_Failed_Consumption'] == 0 and row['#_Failed_Energy Type']==0 and row['#_Failed_Rating']==0):
            lab = 'Failed no tests'          
return lab
```

if one unique value in column it should generate

```
if a>0: 
    print(a)
```

if two unique values in column it should generate

```
if a>0 and b>0: 
    print(a + b)
if a=0 and b>0: 
    print(b)
if a>0 and b=0: 
    print(a)
```

if three unique values in column it should generate

```
if a>0 and b>0 and c>0: 
    print(a + b + c)
if a=0 and b>0 and c>0: 
    print(b + c)
if a>0 and b=0 and c>0: 
    print(a + c)
if a>0 and b>0 and c=0: 
    print(a + b)
if a=0 and b=0 and c>0: 
    print(c)
if a>0 and b=0 and c=0: 
    print(a)
if a=0 and b>0 and c=0: 
    print(b)
```

Essentially I need `2^n - 1` statements generated for `n` unique values.

Comment: But if any of the values are negative, *none* of the `if` statements will succeed.

Comment: That's not valid python, did you mean `a == 0` etc..? If so, you don't need any if's beyond filtering out negative numbers. Adding 0 doesn't change the value so don't bother making a special case.

Comment: In every case, you just want the sum of all the (positive) values, as (for example) `0 + b + c == b + c` when `a == 0`.

Comment: Here is the actual problem that I am trying to solve. Should have started with this in the first place, but made a rookie mistake and oversimplified it.

Comment: Please see 'Update' section above for full code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use multiple variables. Put all the values in a list, then you can loop over it:

```
print(sum(i for i in list_of_values if i > 0))
```

Comment: Thanks Barmar. I have to print a, b and c seperately instead of just sum. Do you have a way for achieving that? Also there are no negative values for a, b and c.

Comment: That's not what your code does, it just prints the total. And if there are no negatives, zero values have no effect on the total.

Comment: If you only want to print the positive values: `print(*(i for i in list_of_values if i > 0))`

Comment: Your question mentions unique values, but nothing in your code filters out duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to write special cases for 0 because you are summing the values and 0 doesn't affect the outcome. Either way, just look at positive numbers, find the unique values > 0 and then sum

```
df.my_column[df.my_column > 0].unique().sum()
```